# Django rest_framework serializer dynamic depth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using a ModelSerializer to serialize a model. How do I have `depth = 1` when retrieving a single instance, and `depth = 0` when retrieving a list.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'organizaton']
        depth = 1    # <--- How to change this to 0 for the list?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `self.instance` in any overridden method.

```
def to_representation(self, value):
    self.Meta.depth = 0 if isinstance(self.instance, list) else 1
    return super().to_representation(value)
```